# How to troubleshoot "iPhoto unable to connect to Photo Stream"?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, photo-stream

When I click "Turn On Photo Stream" on in iPhoto it reports "iPhoto unable to connect to Photo Stream." It shows the correct user name on the Photo Stream screen in iPhoto. I have the correct credentials provided on the iCloud App in System Preferences, and Photo Stream is turned on there.

Running Mac OS X 10.7.2, iPhoto 9.2.1 and iOS 5.0.1. System Updates, App Store and iPhoto reports everything is up to date and running the current version.

I am connected to the Internet and able to visit iCloud.com and log into my account just fine. iTunes, and other apps all seem to work fine.

Comment: I have the same problem and spent 2 hours with three levels of apple technicians on Sunday. They are going to trouble shoot it and get back to me Friday. It seems to be a problem many are having.

Comment: @user13708 Sounds like it might be a server issue. Please let me know what you find out.

Comment: I had the same problem. It looked like it was Little Snitch. Even though I had allowed photostream access in Little Snitch, I found when I deleted the old rule for photostream I got a new request which I allowed again. Then everything started to work as expected.

Comment: I have the same problem .... It appears Mountain Lion is the culprit .... everything has gone wrong since he arrived..
I have no answer .... I HAVE THE PROBLEM .... iPhoto and PhotoStream cannon connect ..... FURIUOS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I went with was to contact Apple's support. After spending about 4 hours on the phone over 3 different occasions the problem still isn't solved. They are going to get back to me again hopefully.

Comment: They never got back to me, but it started working after this latest iCooud update.

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences -> iCloud, Check Photo Stream.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I fixed mine when I realised I'd probably downloaded iPhoto using an AppleID from the App Store but logged into iCloud with a different AppleID. I deleted iPhoto and it's related files (but not the iPhoto Library) using CleanApp, entered the App Store with my usual AppleID and downloaded iPhoto again. Once the App Store, the downloaded iPhoto and iCloud logins were the same iPhoto Stream worked again.